# how to subtract tuple elements in a list of list in pandas and apply a condition?

Tags: pandas, list, numpy, tuples

I have a dataframe as below

df

```
Miles
[(1369, 3503), (1369, 11199), (1369, 15779)]
[(3503, 3503), (3503, 15779)]
[(11199, 15779)]
[]
```

I need to subtract second element of the tuple with the first for every tuple in the list.

I tried this `df['score'] = [i[1] - i[0] for i in df['Miles']]` , but did not get expected results.

Desired output:

```
score 
[2134, 9731, 14410]
[0, 12276]
[4580]
[]
```

And later, I need to apply a condition like np.where(df['score'] > 5000, 'yes', 'no')

```
score_flag
[no, yes, yes]
[no, yes]
[no]
[]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another layer of list comprehension

```
df['score'] = [[i[1] - i[0] for i in x] for x in df['Miles']]
```

Then again:

```
df['score_flag'] = [['Yes' if i > 5000 else 'No' for i in x]
                     for x in df['score']]
```

Output:

```
    Miles                                         score                score_flag
--  --------------------------------------------  -------------------  --------------------
 0  [(1369, 3503), (1369, 11199), (1369, 15779)]  [2134, 9830, 14410]  ['No', 'Yes', 'Yes']
 1  [(3503, 3503), (3503, 15779)]                 [0, 12276]           ['No', 'Yes']
 2  [(11199, 15779)]                              [4580]               ['No']
 3  []                                            []                   []
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Get your first output after `explode`

```
s = df.Miles.explode()
o1 = (s.str[1]-s.str[0]).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
Out[256]: 
0    [2134.0, 9830.0, 14410.0]
1               [0.0, 12276.0]
2                     [4580.0]
3                        [nan]
Name: Miles, dtype: object
```

Get 2nd output

```
(s.str[1]-s.str[0]).dropna().gt(5000).map({True:'Yes',False : 'No'}).groupby(level=0).agg(list).reindex(df.index)
Out[259]: 
0    [No, Yes, Yes]
1         [No, Yes]
2              [No]
3               NaN
Name: Miles, dtype: object
```

Comment: Is there any solution without using explode ?